# Time delayed modal does not pop up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using this code to to have time delayed pop up modal. The end goal is to show  subscription box in the time delayed modal. I have the javascript in . The pop up modal is not working for me.

```js
var count=-1; // initially -1 as we are having a delay of 1000ms

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
    
  count=count+1;
  if (count >=6) //+1 than the req time as we have a delay of 1000ms
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     /////////////what code should go here for the modal to pop up??///////////////////////
      $("#myModal1").modal();
      
     return;
  }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

```html
 <!-- Modal --><span id="timer"></span></h5>

<!-- CODE FOR THE MODAL TO POP UP -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `$('#myModal1').modal('show');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason that this snippet is not working is lack of CSS / JS libraries (jquery + bootstrap). With them modal shows up like intended.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

In bootstrap modal docs there is always string parameter in `modal('')` function so to open it it should be `modal('show')`, but actually code works without it (opens by default). But NOTICE that it could be required for older versions, so maybe this is why you have problems.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/

```js
var count=-1; // initially -1 as we are having a delay of 1000ms

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
    
  count=count+1;
  if (count >=6) //+1 than the req time as we have a delay of 1000ms
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     /////////////what code should go here for the modal to pop up??///////////////////////
      $("#myModal1").modal();
      
     return;
  }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Modal --><span id="timer"></span></h5>

<!-- CODE FOR THE MODAL TO POP UP -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Edit:**

Since you do not actually using bootstrap or any other library, and wanna use plain CSS/JS then all you need to do is: make fixed div with content you need, center it in v/h (flex can be useful) and hide it (display: none). Now with single line of JS code you can display it.

Just style it whatever you want and add functions like close button if needed.

```js
setTimeout(test, 2000);

function test()
{
    document.getElementById('modal1').classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
}

.modal.show {
  display: flex;
}

.modal .modal-content {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt.
  </div>
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nobis praesentium, reprehenderit repellendus libero commodi voluptates numquam autem velit quos aspernatur delectus similique voluptate blanditiis, nemo maxime cumque ab deserunt.
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the missing parts. On my website i am not using bootstrap. When i use the suggested CSS/S libraries (jquery + bootstrap) it messes up my page layout. Is there any other alternative just using HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: Wait, i assumed this is bootstrap because of "modal", so from what library you have modals? Also HTML code of modal looks like bootstrap. So maybe you just copied this code assuming it would work? In plain JS there is not modals, just alerts. So you can write your own, or use any other library with popups.

Comment: I am trying to create it using CSS and JavaScript (if needed).

Comment: So this is actually issue for another question - "how to write popups". You can find thousands of examples in google or just like I said - use some ready to use like SweetAlerts.

Comment: The end goal is to show a subscription box to the user after 5 or 10 seconds. hence,  thought modal could be a good candidate if i can have it in CSS and JavaScript. i might have to look for something using JQuery it seems which i did not want to use to keep the website light weight. Thanks for your suggestion. Really appreciate that.

Comment: For simple single popup you do not really need any library. Just make fixed div with content you need, center it in v/h (flex can be useful) and hide it (display: none). Now with single line of JS code you can display it. That is it.

Comment: I used SweetAlerts and subscription pop up has been implemented. Thanks to you!! I feel that the  subscription pop up might be prone to spam. Any pointer on how to deal with that using captcha or any other method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215200/discussion-between-user2852960-and-chojnicki).